# Filter mails using ConversationID in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Is it possible to filter mails in outlook using ConversationID?

This is what I have tried (filtering on subject) :

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Folders["abc@gmail.com"].Folders["Inbox"];
        string sFolderPath = oInbox.FolderPath;
        string sScope = "SCOPE ('deep traversal of \"" + sFolderPath + "\"')";
        string sFilter = "\"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject\" LIKE '%search%'";
        oApp.AdvancedSearchComplete += new ApplicationEvents_11_AdvancedSearchCompleteEventHandler(oApp_AdvancedSearchComplete);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Search oSearch = oApp.AdvancedSearch(sScope, sFilter, false, "Search results" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oSearchFolder = oSearch.Save("Search results" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

I have already checked [Display email in Outlook by using ConversationID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768016/display-email-in-outlook-by-using-conversationid). It says to search using entryId but I need conversationId.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ConversationID only works in local to track emails in the same email chain`

Comment: Do a google search on the following and look at examples that are given as well `C# Filter mails using ConversationID`

Comment: Hi @DJKRAZE, I did a lot of Google search on this but did not find any proper solution.
Can you give me some pointers ?   Already read these articles : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewdelin/archive/2005/05/11/416312.aspx     http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewdelin/archive/2005/08/08/448882.aspx

Comment: Yes, First link points to this question itself. Second one is related to issue but not to my question. After that links are not much relevant

Comment: Hey @vicky99 have you got any solution for above search?

Comment: @AniketBhansali - There is no quick and direct solution available. I ended up looping on all the items. One improvement you can do is first filter on some other field like "mail sent date".