# Saving object of Mailitem or any property which can be used to invoke Mailitem which was saved

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, comaddin, shared-addin

I am using VS 2010 , Dot Net Framework 2.0 . I have created a project in Extensibility->Shared Add-ins for Outlook.

I want to save Outlook.MailItem Object in a DataTable on explorer_SelectionChange() and use this Outlook.MailItem Object to Manipulate subject and body after-wards.

when i am saving Object of Mailitem in datatable it is getting saved as SYS.ComAddins.
Here is the Code 
Class Variables :

```
private Outlook.MailItem connectingMailItem;
private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
private Outlook.Application applicationObject;
private object addInInstance;
private Outlook.Explorer explorer;
DataTable dtMailItem = new DataTable();
```

OnConnection :

```
    explorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    explorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(explorer_SelectionChange);
    dtMailItem.Columns.Add("MailItem",typeOf(Outlook.MailItem));
    tFollowUp = new Timer();
    tFollowUp.Interval = 100000;
    tFollowUp.Tick += new EventHandler(tFollowUp_Tick);
```

explorer_SelectionChange

```
void explorer_SelectionChange()
{
    if (connectingMailItem != null && connectingMailItem is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connectingMailItem);
        // Perform a Garbage Collection
        GC.Collect();
        connectingMailItem = null;
        return;
    }
    foreach (object selectedItem in explorer.Selection)
    {
        connectingMailItem = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        break;
    }
    if (connectingMailItem != null && connectingMailItem is Outlook.MailItem)
    {                
        dtMailItem.Rows.Add(connectingMailItem);
        dtMailItem.AcceptChanges();
    } 
}
```

tFollowUp_Tick

```
 void tFollowUp_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dtMailItem.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        foreach(DataRow dr in dtMailItem.Rows)
        {
           // Manipulation code for subject and body or remove the Mailitem from Datatable
        }
    }
}
```

How can i save Object of Mailitem or any Property to identify which Mailitem was saved

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you post some code explaining what's the result you're trying to have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try what's suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438219/open-outlook-mail-item-using-entryid-storeid-and-or-pr-entryid) to store the EntryIDand retrieve it later using that same ID.